# Laravel Passport Consume Own API via web issue

Tags: php, laravel, api, axios, laravel-passport

I am running a laravel 5.6 app, everything has been fine until today.

I ran `composer update` for some fixes and there comes the issue.

Passport authentication via `X-CRSF-TOKEN` no longer works.

Looking at the following typical api call via axios, I can tell everything is fine.

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive  
Cookie:remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d=eyJpdiI6IjVBc2hRaFlqQnhoSEREQ1RHU0NROHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNEFqYTRScklzK0VReHl4SWV2V2x6Y0g3SVR0NGo0enhRcVVWbGJ4cm5ubGRwXC85Q2VuVE9EVGxnZTBGRm9cLytnSEpsYVptV0x4Nk8wYnZ2bWFsK2dDODRGTmk2TDk5K0hFSjZuR2k1ZTdlXC9tclNKUmxncVd0U29yZUpUNWxRNDZcL3VDcmFwbjdVRzl1WnczSGN6bnpcLzc4Z0s0cTBTXC80MXIzeVJNZ1krNjhVPSIsIm1hYyI6ImQ5ZWRjZGRhNGMwNTcwYTMzNGI0NTE4YzZmNzQzNDE4YjJlMzU4YTU4OTQ1YWNjMDcyNmU1OTc3ZjAzNGE1YmYifQ%3D%3D; laravel_token=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%3D%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ims5bFc3OFBMWmM0ZlFwQVZtODZlc1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRnBzZ25VQkNuaUM2Z0NwMDMyQ3g5aGdsNk5hM1NXdUl2a2J3VExrRUpMSVBzTFwvMzNjT2U0Q2liQnUrQVNIaUYiLCJtYWMiOiJiNjk0ZjFlZjgxYTkxMjhhNjYwNWU2ZGMwOTQyZDhjYWViZjBiNDk2MTY4OTM2ZjE5ZmZkZTllMWNmZDQ2NzJlIn0%3D;aposhashamura_session=eyJpdiI6ImhTakR5S0dsXC9zbyt5M0JycFg0eVdnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IndEUkp0N0dGWWRGVEFUQVVlOWZ5VnYyQ0ZHUk1cLzhUbHlnZVJSM21YSVFSS0xUXC9BaTBqeTJrRkZiV0RqdzhIVCIsIm1hYyI6IjFlZGJlYzE4MDEzOTIyNTAxYWYxNzE5N2VhNzExY2M5ZWZlNWM4ZWZkNDM4OTE3NzEzOTRjYWQxZWFmMzI5OGYifQ%3D%3D
Host: somewhereonmymachine.my
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://somewhereonmymachine.my/backoffice/reports/admin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: rzLjJ0tIqo1he0k9wxypE8O685iLjmpEuRNFtP7C
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Socket-Id: 125019.15490345
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6Ims5bFc3OFBMWmM0ZlFwQVZtODZlc1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRnBzZ25VQkNuaUM2Z0NwMDMyQ3g5aGdsNk5hM1NXdUl2a2J3VExrRUpMSVBzTFwvMzNjT2U0Q2liQnUrQVNIaUYiLCJtYWMiOiJiNjk0ZjFlZjgxYTkxMjhhNjYwNWU2ZGMwOTQyZDhjYWViZjBiNDk2MTY4OTM2ZjE5ZmZkZTllMWNmZDQ2NzJlIn0=
```

I have done a lot of Googling but I cannot seem to figure out the qualms.

`\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class` has always been last entry of `$middlewareGroups` in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

ANyone?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: refer this https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/564 hope it helps you

Comment: show your bootstrap.js and app.js

Comment: @samo Sorry I am getting Unauthenticated as Api Response.

Comment: @samo again, it is setting `laravel_token` look at the question it is there in the browser dump

Comment: @AfrazAhmad, I guess you expect to see this:
`let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}`

Comment: add error in your question

Comment: @Temitayo if you're getting 401 error that means your session is expired, logout and login again it will be fine again

Answer (score -1):

If anyone every falls into this problem, after update, try rollback your update or just simply run `php artisan key:generate`.

That should fix it.